# Error: no device found Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6010, description '*' When trying to debug ESP32-S3 on macOS

Tags: debugging, arduino-esp32, openocd

Trying to debug ESP32-S3 with PlatformIO on VSCode with macOS on M1.

Installed ftdi drivers from their website. (installed the VCP drivers, not the D3XX ones as I couldn't find a way to compile and install them).

As ESP32-S3 has an internal debugger, I just created a USB that connects D-/D+ pins to the board gpio 19 and 20 (and grd). BTW, when I connect it to the macbook, I dont see any additional port under /dev/*

Getting the following error, regardless of my platform.ini configuration.

```
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 20000 kHz

adapter speed: 5000 kHz

Info : tcl server disabled
Info : telnet server disabled
Error: no device found
Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6010, description '*', serial '*' at bus location '*'
Error: no device found
Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6014, description '*', serial '*' at bus location '*'

.pioinit:11: Error in sourced command file:
Remote connection closed
```

My platformio.ini:

```
[env:esp32-s3-devkitc-1]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32-s3-devkitc-1
framework = arduino
upload_port = /dev/cu.wchusbserial553C0085431
monitor_speed=115200
build_type = debug
debug_init_break = tbreak setup
;debug_tool = esp-builtin
debug_tool =  esp-prog
```

Removed and installed the ftdi drivers.
Got a similar error when trying with ESP-IDF.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting the USB conector directly on esp32s3 module, you should try to change the board parameter from *esp32-s3-devkitc-1* to *esp32s3-builtin*. This way you specify that you are using the built-in debugger.

Comment: Please mention the steps too. Thanks!